# Creating a general log sheet for CTD and ADCP for fieldwork

Tags: oceanography

It is close to the deadline for conducting research on a research vessel for the Irish Sea (one month left). I'm currently a student and would like some descriptive observational data/variables needed to account for when recording measurements from CTD (conductivity, Temperature, Depth) and ADCP (Acoustic Doppler Current Profile) instruments. For both CTD and ADCP, what do I need from these devices to create a general log sheet suitable for all students (my crew) to record during the trip.

Answer (score 1):

This answer might be a bit late but here are some common metadata variables that get recorded:

For a CTD:

- Operator
- Date and time
- Start and end co-ordinates of station
- Station Number
- Sample depths (assuming you'll also be collecting water samples)

  - Here you can also record what the water samples are used for i.e. salinities, chemistry etc
- Sea state
- Vessel
- File name

For the ADCP:

- Start and end co-ordinates
- Date and time
- ADCP type
- Set-up (sampling frequency, bin size)
- Vessel
- Operator
- File name